# Ornamental Cherry Tree Root breaching lawn

Tags: roots, damage

We have a 10-year-old 20 ft high ornamental cherry tree that has a root that is causing a bump in the lawn that I am scalping when I mow and is raising the brick surrounding the tree.
Is it OK to remove this root without damaging the tree?  I would guess the root is about 1 1/2 in diameter.  I can cut the bricks to accommodate the root but the bulge in the lawn is a trip hazard.

Comment: „Brick surrounding the tree”? Uh… not sure that’s a good idea. Could you please add a photo or so?

Comment: Pleased [edit] to include picture or pictures (use the "sun and mountains" icon at the top of the edit box.)

Comment: Perhaps you could mulch a generous diameter around the tree.  Put down cardboard first and the mulch should be thick to prevent the grass from coming back up through the cardboard and mulch.